# the logout button in actionbar shows up in emulator but not in android mobil

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-studio

I was just adding a log out button in the action bar. It worked in emulator but when i install that apk in mobil the log out button is absent. 
It works perfectly when i use emulator to test but not in real device or mobil its not working.please can anyone help me with this ? I have spent whole day on this but could not figured out what is happening. Its being an emergency please anyone . Thanks in advance.I have tried following code:

```
private android.app.ActionBar actionBar;
 actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Hide the action bar title
  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionmenu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.getTitle(),
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_refresh:
            // refresh
            Intent intent = new Intent(Autofill.this, Main.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

R.menu.actionmenu.xml file contains :

```
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>

        <!-- Help -->
```

Comment: can you please mention the Android version of your testing device.

Comment: Hello. What about yours R.menu.actionmenu xml? How it looks? Is there android:showAsAction="ifRoom" flag?

Comment: R.menu.actionmenu xml contains only one item..

Comment: It could be that your phone has a "physical" menu button and that's where you can find it

Comment: @jani i am testing my app in mobil having version 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

The option is positioned if there is room, so ...

You could change **ifRoom** with **always**

Other options:

["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]" | "collapseActionView"]